# Will cassandra support secondary indices which contain additional attributes for insert-only tables?

Tags: cassandra

Is there a possibility for a secondary index to contain another attributes beside key values? For example transaction key and transaction amount. In that way I could calculate everything I need by just using this index.

I see why it is difficult to maintain in cassandra but for insert-only, non-updatable tables cassandra could easily support these kind of indices.